# PHP curl: how to get posted body as a string?

Tags: php, curl

I'm sending a file with `'@'.$filename` using curl and for debug purposes I'd like to get a string that curl actually POST-ed. Is this possible?

**Edit:**
Sorry, originally I've only stated in the tags that it's about PHP. Also, @filename in php makes php create and send a multipart/form-data request, and I want to see it, so just printing $post will not help me here.

Comment: Are you POST'ing to your local server? If you are, you could simply `var_dump` the `$_POST` global.

Answer (score 0):

Do a `print_r($_POST)` wrapped between `<pre>` and `</pre>` (without spaces)

Answer (score 0):

You may use the `--trace-ascii` option with your curl command like this:

`curl -v http://example.com/route -d "data=one&test=two" --trace-ascii /dev/stdout`